# serving an image file on NestJS always gets 404 error

Tags: node.js, nestjs, nest

I'm working on NestJS. I want to serve image files to clients. But it is not working.

Here is my project structure.

```
/MyProject
    /src
        app.module.ts
        ..
/uploads
    myimage.png
```

The image files are in **/uploads**. Furthermore, I have set the prefix url in the **main.ts** like this,

```
app.setGlobalPrefix('file');
```

Here is my **ServeStaticModule** inside app.module.ts,

```
    ServeStaticModule.forRoot({
      rootPath: join(__dirname, '..', '../../uploads'),
      serveRoot: '/public/'
    })
```

When I try to access the image like,

http://localhost:5004/file/public/myimage.png or

http://localhost:5004/public/myimage.png or

http://localhost:5004/file/public/uploads/myimage.png or

http://localhost:5004/public/uploads/myimage.png or

I will get 404 error from the server.

The error is like this

{"message":"Cannot GET /file/public/myimage.png","error":"Not Found","statusCode":404}

Thanks for every helps.